# Scheduled query returning "Procedure not found"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gcloud

We have created a scheduled query on Google's BigQuery API that should call a routine `main_routine` that is present in a dataset `analytics`:

```
call analytics.main_routine()
```

The region of the dataset and the scheduled query is the same (`us`).

Every job execution of this scheduled query is returning the following error:

```
Procedure is not found: analytics.main_routine at [1:6];
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you schedule the query,  it fails with `Procedure not found: analytics.main_routine at [1:6]`   because it runs on a multi region (US).

Please try to schedule the query on a specific [region](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specify_locations) (single region - us-central1) and let me know if it worked or not.

**Multi-region :**

[image]

**Single region:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure, Project name is included when calling the procedure as below:

```
call <Project_name>.<Dataset_Name>.<Procedure_Name>();
```

Comment: It wasn't originally, just `<Dataset_Name>.<Procedure_Name>();`, tried adding the project name as well but it returned the same error